# How To Perform OAuth 2.0 using the Twitter Search API and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I want to allow users on my web app to authenticate using OAuth and the Twitter Search API. My goal is to make the request using AngularJS. I am using `$resource` to send the request, but I am having some trouble with my code. Can anybody help me here?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('TwitterCtrl', ['$scope', '$resource', function (scope, resource) {

//    scope.clientId = 'XXXXXXXXX';
//    scope.apiKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    scope.token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

        var twitterOAuth = resource('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token='+scope.token);
        twitterOAuth.get()
        .$promise.then(function(){
            scope.twitter = resource('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json',
                {
                    q:'AngularJS'
                }
            );
            scope.twitter.get();
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: I think using angular for OAuth without any backend is not a good idea: The angularjs code can be read by any website user and in order to send the oauth request you will MOST likely have to send an api key aswell. This api key will be readable for any user and therefor "stolen" from you.